# Service Stack put data in variables instead of database

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use service Stack to store data in my database.
With the example MovieService a simple HTTP POST allows to store data.
http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.MovieRest/

I would like put some of these posted data in a variable without store it in my database.
With those data I will be able to make some SQL requests to get some foreign KEYs.
I would like to know if this is possible? And if yes give me a tips to do it. 
Thank you

Comment: -1 What's the question? This seems to be a list of requirements, without a specific problem. StackOverflow is about getting help with specific issues, not for requesting code. If you post what you have done, and where you have gotten stuck, and what you have tried to do to resolve it, then we can help. And [ServiceStack has great documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) to teach you step by step about the features, it's advisable to start there.

Comment: I edited my post Scott, I thought my question was explicit. I already read the documentation, I just begin to work with service stack and C# so yes I ask to code example because I have no clue how to do it

Comment: It's entirely possible to store posted data in a variable and not require a database. But StackOverflow is not for requesting specific examples or code you would like implemented. The goal of StackOverflow is not to teach you to program with c# or ServiceStack, to which you say you are new. The aim is to provide advise on specific problems that you have encountered having made an attempt. I don't mean to be blunt, but if you have read the documentation, as you claim, and you can't attempt a solution, then your c# skills are probably insufficient to use this technology.

Comment: RESTful services are quite an ambitious topic for somebody new to c#. Perhaps you should look into `List<T>`, `static` variables and LINQ for querying and apply that to the most basic ServiceStack step-by-step tutorial from the documentation. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott for your tips. To be honest I would like use something more basic to begin but my manager decided otherwise... When you are new in a company you don't really decide so I try. Thanks again

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mean to come off harshly, and I understand the predicament that your manager has put you in. It is unreasonable for them to expect you to learn two new technologies that have to co-exist, as this is an advanced topic. There are some [example solutions here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples) you may wish to take a look at and adapt.

Comment: It's ok I understand what irritate you in my question, I have to learn and not expect to get everything that easily. I will take some time to read and make some tests. When I will found the solution I will update this post. Thank you again Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok It was super easy, there is my code (copy from ServiceStack.MovieRest example):

```
/// <summary>
///     Define your ServiceStack web service request (i.e. Request DTO).
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The route is defined here rather than in the AppHost.</remarks>
[Api("GET or DELETE a single movie by Id. Use POST to create a new LifetouchRespRate and PUT to update it")]
[Route("/movies", "POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE")]
[Route("/movies/{Id}")]
public class Movie : IReturn<MovieResponse>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the movie.
    /// </summary>
    public Movie()
    {
        this.Genres = new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the id of the movie. The id will be automatically incremented when added.
    /// </summary>
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ImdbId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string TagLine { get; set; }
    public List<string> Genres { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     Define your ServiceStack web service response (i.e. Response DTO).
/// </summary>
public class MovieResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the movie.
    /// </summary>
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///     Create your ServiceStack restful web service implementation.
/// </summary>
public class MovieService : Service
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     GET /movies/{Id}
    /// </summary>
    public MovieResponse Get(Movie movie)
    {
        return new MovieResponse
                   {
                       Movie = Db.Id<Movie>(movie.Id),
                   };
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     POST /movies
    ///     returns HTTP Response =>
    ///     201 Created
    ///     Location: http://localhost/ServiceStack.MovieRest/movies/{newMovieId}
    ///     {newMovie DTO in [xml|json|jsv|etc]}
    /// </summary>
    public object Post(Movie movie)
    {
        Db.Insert(movie);
        var newMovieId = Db.GetLastInsertId();

        var newMovie = new MovieResponse
                           {
                               Movie = Db.Id<Movie>(newMovieId),
                           };

        return new HttpResult(newMovie)
                   {
                       StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
                       Headers =
                           {
                               {HttpHeaders.Location, base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(newMovieId.ToString())}
                           }
                   };           
    }
```

In the class MovieService it is the below raw to register data in the database, so just delete it to don't save in the database:

```
Db.Insert(movie);
```

So to create variable to get all information I can process like this:

```
        String imdbid = movie.ImdbId;
        String title = movie.Title;
        decimal rating = movie.Rating;
```

I made this manipulation because is receive data from an other application via an http-post, I have to share all information from one post, on several tables. I use an SQL request to found my Primary key with information I get.

Thank you for your links Scott it's help me a lot. I know it's look really easy for you but for a beginner like me it's a bit tricky and so cool when you got it :) Cheers!